# Is there a way to find the specific letter starting any position in excel

Tags: excel

I have a string called "Ambedkar" in excel. Is there a way to find "k" starting from 4th position( the "e" in Ambedkar). The expected answer should be 2 because k is 2 digits after e. Please guide

Answer (score 0):

You can use this UDF:

```
Function ambedkar(inpText As String, position As Integer, target As String)

temp = Right(inpText, Len(inpText) - position)

For i = 1 To Len(temp)
    If Mid(temp, i, 1) = target Then
        ambedkar = i
    End If
Next i

End Function
```

However, you need to reference the third argument (target) from a cell in excel. I don't know why but otherwise it gives an error.